# I was told by a vendor who licenses their paid software under GPL v2 that I cannot include the software inside my framework. How so?

Tags: gpl-2, copyleft, paid-software

They're a pretty decently sized company within the space and I assume they did their due diligence and so, I'm wondering if I misunderstood something. Are you not allowed to include paid software (A) that is licensed to you under GPL v2 if:

- The overall product (B) you're building using (A) is also GPL v2
- I include their license and also give credit.

I am not sub-licensing/re-selling, as they told me. I am simply using their software to make mine work.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Nitpick: GNU is the organisation. The open-source _license_ is the General Public License, often abbreviated to GPL, and often referred to for clarity as the GNU GPL.

Comment: Are you sure that's what they said? I think that the "if" should be an "unless". GNUv2 **allows** (not not allow) you to include code into yours if your code is also GNUv2 and you include the copyright and license of the included code - exactly what they say but opposite

Comment: how was the software conveyed/distributed to you? this will probably be an important factor; for example, if you work-for-hire, you can't just take a copy your employer's code home with you; on the other hand, if you downloaded something from a publicly accessible website, you probably can reuse it

Comment: Is this one of those companies that distributes their code under GPL but for a fee will license it to you under different terms? I ask because if that's the case they could be confused thinking you want to sell your stuff with a more standard enterprise-y license without sharing your source code. Many companies do this precisely to make money off of other companies who want to use the GPL code but not share their own code.

Comment: @slebetman Or that's the OP's [correct] interpretation of the licence, rather than a quote from the vendor.

Comment: Literally interpreted, you cannot "copy" GPL v2. There is no language that considers copying without ultimate distribution (why?) Nonetheless if you are not distributing, you can pretty much do what you like with GPL v2, unless you violate another license or agreement. A vendor can require that this software is not used with their own (distinct) product. The isolation should be clear.

Comment: @CaptainMan if you're using a dual license library, you may not be able to select one license type then switch to another later.  If you paid for a license, you can't then change your mind and start using the GPL license, no matter if you abide by all the terms of the GPL from that point forward.

Comment: @MarkRansom Why not? You have a GPL license, why can't you use it? (See GPL clause 6 which says, "Each time you redistribute the Program (or any work based on the Program), the recipient automatically receives a license from the original licensor to copy, distribute or modify the Program subject to these terms and conditions."

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't remember the details, but I remember there's a software that is quite militant about this point.  Might have been Qt.

Comment: That is a *great* question, and I hope one of you asks it.  Please don't, however, continue discussing it in this comments field.

Answer (score 23):

Assuming that the original work was distributed under the GNU GPLv2, and that you have made a work which is a derivative of it (in copyright terms), you may redistribute your derivative work subject to [GPLv2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html) ss 2 and 3.

The point of distributing under the GPL is to enable a work to continue to be used and/or repurposed by as large a number of people as possible.  That said, in my experience people and organisations do occasionally release under the GPL without fully understanding what they are permitting<sup>1</sup>.  Sadly for them, there are no take-backs from people who have already acquired a copy under those terms (see eg [my article](https://lwn.net/Articles/747563/): "*the license is irrevocable once even partial performance has occurred*").

In this case the licensor seems to be unwilling, so you will need to be **very, very** sure of your grounds before you proceed.  Read the section entitled "*How to Apply These Terms to Your New Programs*" at the end of the GPL.  If the licensor has done **everything** the GPL recommends, you have good grounds for believing that the work was licensed to you on those terms.  If, by way of example on the other hand, you downloaded it from a page titled "*Here's our GPL software*" but the code made no mention of that, then you might want to be a great deal more hesitant.  If anything of significance (eg your business, or your house) rests on this you will want to take professional legal advice, which this is not, before proceeding.

But assuming you do proceed, then as long as you obey the requirements of GPLv2, particularly ss 2 and 3, with respect to your derivative work, then you should be OK.

---

<sup>1</sup>See by way of example the [sad fate of SleepyHead](https://jedimark.net/2019/02/08/sleepyhead-project-shutdown/), wherein the highly-dedicated lead developer generously published his work under GPL, putting in thousands of hours of his own development time while failing to understand how free software development works.  He then completely lost it when other people dared to take the current code and release it.  He halted all development and walked away from the project (as is completely his right), concluding "*Friends don’t let friends release full blown complex applications under the GPL*".

Final note for anyone interested in sleep apnoea and free software: the fork survived and is doing nicely, at https://gitlab.com/pholy/OSCAR-code .

Comment: "you may redistribute your derivative work subject to GPLv2 ***ss*** 2 and 3." -- Typo?

Comment: "ss" is an abbreviation for "section" or "sections".

Comment: Note that if they have not followed the GPL recommendations, but are claiming their code is GPL licensed, I'm fairly certain that the FSF will want to hear about it, as that would likely be a case of either a company in need of legal education about such things or a company which is willfully misrepresenting things (or possibly violating license terms).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn don't forget that the licence is not binding on the original author.  If they are not *required* to follow the GPL, then they are not required to follow it in any particular way.  This is merely about trying to be as sure as possible that they clearly expressed a desire to convey the code under GPLv2 at the time, so that they cannot later claim that such was not their intention.

Comment: @MadHatter I had noticed the goodbye notice, but not the story behind it. Could you summarize or provide a link to a summary?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I recall digging into it and reading through what was public on mailing lists (I have no personal knowledge of any of the people involved) at the time, but I can't find it now, so I will try a brief summary from memory.  There was some perception that the Original Developer was dragging his heels on release, whereas his perception was that he wanted the code to be just-right before stamping it as a release.  Others took what was currently available and put it up on another server as their release tarball.  OD took umbrage, then flight.

Comment: Basically it looked to me like a cathedral-model OD and some bazaar-model enthusiasts/assistants, and a complete failure by the OD to understand that when you release code under a free licence, other people can do what they like with it.  If he'd've come here I'd've advised him to go for CC BY-ND, except of course that such a question would've been off-topic.  **Please accept my apologies if any of the above is remembered wrong.**

Comment: @MadHatter Ah so he was very disappointed that he did not have full control.  Didn't they call it an unofficial milestone release or something, so it was very clear that they weren't taking anything away from him?